# Why there is no macro to cut bad_weak_ptr which is derived from std::exception

Tags: c++, boost

I'm porting BOOST to my TI embeded platform, it is common that exception is not supported in emebeded envrionment and so my TI embeded platoform does. So that I use BOOST_EXCEPTION_DISABLE and BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS to cut exception from BOOST as guided by BOOST CONFIG http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/config/doc/html/index.html

But interesting thing is, for bad_weak_ptr, it's declared as derived from std::exception without any macro in :

```
#if defined(__BORLANDC__) && __BORLANDC__ <= 0x564
# pragma option push -pc
#endif

class bad_weak_ptr: public std::exception
{
public:

    virtual char const * what() const throw()
    {
        return "tr1::bad_weak_ptr";
    }
};

#if defined(__BORLANDC__) && __BORLANDC__ <= 0x564
# pragma option pop
#endif
```

I would like to ask, how to cut the bad_weak_ptr from BOOST? why BOOST do not give a macro to cut the exception dependent class in case the exception itself is already been cut?

Comment: Please don't put things like `[BOOST]` in your title - that is why we have tags. This isn't a forum.

Comment: well I don't know c++ well enough to know the answer, but... can you have an exception object without actually being able to throw it?

Comment: Can't you submit a feature request? If the exception is not being thrown there should be no issue to just comment/ifdef this declaration

Answer (score 0):

There are some dirty tricks to get around this, if you must.  If you create your own std::exception class in an appropriately named header file and place it first in the include path, the compiler should pick it up instead.  But just realize that this should be well documented as it is a hack.

In a broader sense, I think perhaps you should consider why you're using Boost in the first place. Boost has a larger footprint and wasn't designed for small systems. And the BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS solution is a far cry from proper error propagation and handling.  Seems to me the better choice would be to take Boost--exceptions and all, or use something else more appropriate.

Comment: Hi, I doubt that creating my own std::exception might result in changing the attribute of the derived class, because the derived class might use something(type, operation, eg) in the base class std::exception. and I want to use BOOST because some of it is the c++11 source library, it's more widely spread and should have more stable and performance advantage, and it integrate many useful C++11 feature all together so that I do not need to port one feature some place and port other features in other places.

Comment: Technically defining your own type in `std` namespace violates the standard and leads to [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). In this case we're not really talking about a full standard library (I think conformance requirements are reduced for "standalone" compilers, although I don't know much about that)

Comment: @sehe Agreed.  This is operating well outside the standards here and relying on compiler implementations.

Comment: @LiuNick, if you must have this functionality, it may be best to allow those exception classes to exist within your binary, but just not using them yourself.  It might be hard to verify that they never ever get thrown by supporting code, but if you put a single exception handler at the top of your thread stack, you could handle any errant exceptions the same as a process signal.